# Kafka with Docker dynamic advertised_host_name

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I've been using wurstmeister/Kafka for a few weeks now in Dev and QA, but in each case I need to hard-code `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` to the IP of the box that it's on, using `docker-compose`. This hasn't been a problem during testing, but now that I'm trying to scale this out to production, it's becoming a little bit more frustrating.

I'm continuing to use `docker-compose` to somewhat manually deploy three instances of Kafka and Zookeper onto three separate cloud hosts. I've opened up the appropriate ports, and attempted everything in my limited Docker knowledge to dynamically assign `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME`. Much to my dismay, it always yields some sort of error. The README on docker hub mentions assigning this variable dynamically VIA
`HOSTNAME_COMMAND, e.g. HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "route -n | awk '/UG[ \t]/{print $$2}'"`

This causes my application to obtain a connection refused response when attempting to connect. However, manually assigning the IP to the three hosts works perfectly fine. What am I missing here?!

Comment: What are you using to manage the docker-compose service's on your cloud host? So when it reboots, how do they start up again?

Comment: Currently, nothing. This is all reasonably manual to try and meet a rush deadline. Afterwards we will be going back and either using Kubernetes, or hopefully as Swarm gains a bit more traction and maturity, we can leverage docker-compose with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compose can [substitute variables into configuration options](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) at run time.

#### Compose Environment variables

Set the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` container environment variable to a local variable called `DOCKER_HOST_IP`.

```
whatever:
  environment:
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: ${DOCKER_HOST_IP}
```

Then `DOCKER_HOST_IP` needs to be set whenever you run `docker-compose`. You will get a warning from `docker-compose` when it's not set.

#### IP on the Docker host

Running `ip route show` will list the default interface.
Then `ip address show` will give you the ip addresses.

To get these into a variable

```
default_interface=$(ip ro sh | awk '/^default/{ print $5; exit }')
export DOCKER_HOST_IP=$(ip ad sh $default_interface | awk '/inet /{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1)
[ -z "$DOCKER_HOST_IP" ] && (echo "No docker host ip address">&2; exit 1 )
echo "$DOCKER_HOST_IP"
```

You can add those commands to whatever your startup script is, or create a standalone script from them to call when you need it.

#### IP via Docker Machine

If you are managing a remote `docker-machine` you can get the ip via the [machine environment](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/).

```
DOCKER_HOST_IP=$(docker-machine ip ${DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME})
```

Comment: I am indeed managing a remote docker-machine, this looks good, I'll give this a go in the morning!